# useRef doesn't work on large screen sizes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm creating an email form in Nextjs13 and have a strange issue. My useRef hooks aren't working on large screen sizes. I can get the information from the text inputs and post to my API on mobile screen sizes but on my actual laptop screen size they don't work and don't throw any errors.

I'm testing with mobile via chrome dev tools so they are both in the same local host browser. I must be overlooking something here...

```js
"use client";
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function DemoForm() {
  const nameRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const emailRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const messageRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);

  const onSubmitEmail = (data: any) => {
    const params = { email: data.email, message: data.message };
    axios.post("/api/sendEmail", params).then((res) => console.log(res));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (
      !nameRef.current?.value ||
      !emailRef.current?.value ||
      !messageRef.current?.value
    ) {
      return;
    }

    const formData = {
      name: nameRef.current.value,
      email: emailRef.current.value,
      message: messageRef.current.value,
    };

    // Perform form submission logic here
    onSubmitEmail(formData);

    // Reset the form after submission
    if (nameRef.current) nameRef.current.value = "";
    if (emailRef.current) emailRef.current.value = "";
    if (messageRef.current) messageRef.current.value = "";
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="hidden sm:block">
        <section className="mt-20">
          <h1 className="font-sans uppercase font-bold text-8xl leading-tight">
            Contact
          </h1>
          <form className="flex flex-col" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Name"
              ref={nameRef}
              className="input input-ghost p-0 w-full max-w-xs mb-5"
            />
            <input
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              ref={emailRef}
              className="input input-ghost p-0 w-full max-w-xs mb-5"
            />
            <textarea
              className="textarea textarea-ghost p-0 mb-5 w-6/12"
              placeholder="Message"
              ref={messageRef}
            ></textarea>
            <button
              className="dropShadowBtn btn btn-md btn-primary rounded-md uppercase w-2/12"
              type="submit"
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        </section>
      </div>
      {/* mobile */}
      <div className="sm:hidden">
        <section className="mt-20">
          <h1 className="font-sans uppercase font-bold text-5xl leading-tight">
            Contact
          </h1>
          <form className="flex flex-col" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Name"
              ref={nameRef}
              className="input input-ghost p-0 w-full max-w-xs mb-5"
            />
            <input
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              ref={emailRef}
              className="input input-ghost p-0 w-full max-w-xs mb-5"
            />
            <textarea
              className="textarea textarea-ghost p-0 mb-5 w-6/12"
              placeholder="Message"
              ref={messageRef}
            ></textarea>
            <button
              className="dropShadowBtn btn btn-md btn-primary rounded-md uppercase w-2/12"
              type="submit"
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        </section>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```